# GET PROCESSING OPTIONS Response

Tags: smartcard, apdu, emv

I am trying to understand how to create a CDOL1 for a smart card, and the applet developer has been less than helpful. When I send a GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command to the card, I get this response:

```
80 0E 7D 00 40 01 01 00 48 01 03 01 50 01 03 00 90 00
```

I have been trying to understand what that 7D template is and how should I construct the CDOL, but have so far found nothing. I was hoping someone with more experience could help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### GET PROCESSING OPTIONS

According to "[**EMV Book 3** - Application Specification](http://emvco.com/specifications.aspx)", **Tag 0x80 Format 1** reply for *GET PROCESSING OPTIONS* contained:

- x82: Application Interchange Profile (**AIP**),
- x94: Application File Locator (**AFL**).

*Please keep in mind that Tag 0x80 formats are different for different APDU Commands.*

Your APDU Data reply with EMV TLV Tag 0x80 Format 1 data contains (2 bytes) with **AIP** and **AFL** with 3 Records (4 bytes each, 12 bytes in total):

```
TLVs:  # EMV, Tag + Length + Value (TLV) series
- x80:  # EMV, Template, Response Message Format 1
   tag: "80"
   len: "0E" #   // 14
   val: "7D00400101004801030150010300" # Template, Response Message Format 1.
   - AIP:  # Application Interchange Profile, Tag 0x82
       B01: "7D"
           # _1______ - bit 7, SDA supported
           # __1_____ - bit 6, DDA supported
           # ___1____ - bit 5, Cardholder verification is supported
           # ____1___ - bit 4, Terminal Risk Management is to be performed
           # _____1__ - bit 3, Issuer Authentication is supported
           # _______1 - bit 1, Combined DDA/AC Generation is supported
       B02: "00" # RFU
   - AFL:  # Application File Locator, Tag 0x94
    - S1:  # AFL Record
       B01: "40" # SFI [xxxxx___]  // 8
       B02: "01" # From record  // 1
       B03: "01" # To record  // 1
       B04: "00" # First hashed
    - S2:  # AFL Record
       B01: "48" # SFI [xxxxx___]  // 9
       B02: "01" # From record  // 1
       B03: "03" # To record  // 3
       B04: "01" # First hashed  // 1
    - S3:  # AFL Record
       B01: "50" # SFI [xxxxx___]  // 10
       B02: "01" # From record  // 1
       B03: "03" # To record  // 3
       B04: "00" # First hashed
```

### Data Object List (DOL)

The format for EMV Data Object List (**DOL**) defined in the same EMV Book 3.
There are several **DOL** tags used in EMV world. For sample:

- x8C: Card Risk Management DOL 1 (**CDOL1**),
- x8D: Card Risk Management DOL 2 (**CDOL2**),
- x97: Transaction Certificate DOL (**TDOL**),
- x9F38: Processing Options DOL (**PDOL**),
- x9F49: Dynamic Data Object List (**DDOL**).

All **DOL** Tags follow the same format rule - The Tag Value contains the **Series** of **Tag_ID + Length** bytes without Value parts.

The sample with CDOL1 - Tag 0x8C, Length 0x15 (21 bytes) and Value parsing.

https://iso8583.info/cmd/EMV/TLVs?8C159F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704

```
---
TLVs:#"8C159F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704" # EMV, Tag + Length + Value (TLV) series
- x8C:#"8C159F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704" # EMV, Card Risk Management DOL 1 (CDOL1)
  - tag: "8C"
  - len: "15" #  // 21
  - val:#"9F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704" # Card Risk Management DOL 1 (CDOL1).
    - x9F02:#"9F0206" # EMV, Authorised Amount (Numeric)
      - tag: "9F02"
      - len: "06"
    - x9F03:#"9F0306" # EMV, Amount, Other (Numeric)
      - tag: "9F03"
      - len: "06"
    - x9F1A:#"9F1A02" # EMV, Country Code, Terminal
      - tag: "9F1A"
      - len: "02"
    - x95:#"9505" # EMV, Terminal Verification Results (TVR)
      - tag: "95"
      - len: "05"
    - x5F2A:#"5F2A02" # ISO 7816, Currency Code, Transaction
      - tag: "5F2A"
      - len: "02"
    - x9A:#"9A03" # EMV, Date, Transaction
      - tag: "9A"
      - len: "03"
    - x9C:#"9C01" # EMV, Transaction Type
      - tag: "9C"
      - len: "01"
    - x9F37:#"9F3704" # EMV, Unpredictable Number
      - tag: "9F37"
      - len: "04"
```

**CDOL1** Tag describes the list of **Tags** and their **Lengths** which real **Values** need to be included into *First GENERATE APPLICATION CRYPTOGRAM (AC)* APDU Request Data.

### GENERATE APPLICATION CRYPTOGRAM (AC)

SmartCard APDU Request data for First Generate AC Command contained **Series of Values** mentioned in **CDOL1**. **CDOL2** used for Second Generate AC.

Here is the sample for Generate AC APDU Command and Tag 0x80 Format 1 template in the Response (related to Generate AC Command).

```
> 80 AE 80 00 1D 000000001000 000000000000 0442 0000000000 0978 150310 00 11223344
< 80 12 80 0001 0102030405060708 06010A03A40000 9000

AE: # EMV, Generate AC
- rq:  # ISO 7816-3, Case 4
   CLA: "80" # Class byte
   INS: "AE" # Instruction
 - P1P2:  # Parameters 1 and 2
  - P1: "80" # Parameter 1
       # 10______ - bits 8-7, Authorisation Request Cryptogram (ARQC)
    P2: "00" # Parameter 2
 - LcData: 
    len: "1D" # // 29
  - val: "0000000010000000000000000372000000000009781112120000000000"
     x9F02: "000000001000" # EMV, Authorised Amount (Numeric) // 100
     x9F03: "000000000000" # EMV, Amount, Other (Numeric) // 0
     x9F1A: "0442" # EMV, Country Code, Terminal // 442 - Luxembourg
     x95: "0000000000" # EMV, Terminal Verification Results (TVR)
     x5F2A: "0978" # ISO 7816, Currency Code, Transaction // 978 - euro
     x9A: "150310" # EMV, Date, Transaction.  // 2015.03.10
     x9C: "00" # EMV, Transaction Type.  // Purchase / Sale
     x9F37: "11223344" # EMV, Unpredictable Number
- rs:  # Response
 - SW1SW2:  # Status byte 1 and 2
    SW1: "90" # Status byte 1  // Normal processing
    SW2: "00" # Status byte 2
 - DATA:
  - x80: 
     tag: "80"
     len: "12" #   // 18
   - val:  # Template, Response Message Format 1.
    - x9F27:  # EMV, Cryptogram Information Data (CID)
       val: "80" # Cryptogram Information Data (CID).
       # 10______ - bits 8-7, ARQC
       # _____000 - bits 3-1 (Reason/Advice/Referral Code), No information given
     + x9F36: "0001" # EMV, Application Transaction Counter (ATC)
     + x9F26: "0102030405060708" # EMV, Cryptogram, Application
     + x9F10: "06010A03A40000" # EMV, Issuer Application Data (IAD)
```

More details about the procedures and flows in [EMV specifications](http://emvco.com/specifications.aspx) available for free at **EMVCo** site.

Parsing samples were done with online [EMV and APDU data parsers](https://iso8583.info/lib/EMV/).

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Maybe you could extend it with a description how to read records from the parsed AFL to get card data (and especially tag '8C' with CDOL1).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Why  _AIP_ and _AFL_ tags themselves (i.e. **0x82** and **0x94**) are not included in the response? (in questioner's response, i.e. `80 0E 7D 00 40 01 01 00 48 01 03 01 50 01 03 00` for example)? How the parser detect AIP and AFL borders? Does they have fixed order and lengths always? (i.e. 2 bytes and 12 bytes lengths and first AIP and after that AFL in a the response)

Comment: Tag 0x80 Format 1 contained fixed structure order and fixed sub-fields lengths except the last in the structure list. For Get Processing Option it is Fixed 2 bytes with AIP and AFL with variable length depending of count of AFL's records - as defined in the 1st part of answer. The structure for Tag 0x80 is different depending of used APDU command.